# Populate gridview from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

is there a javascript where I can populate a gridview from the database? For example is there a javascript for this code?
 gvRFPCorpCode is the name of my gridview

```
private void fillCorpCode()
    {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            data.gRowId = this.txtROWID.Text;

            ds = data.GetCorpCode();

            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.gvRFPCorpCode.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    this.gvRFPCorpCode.DataBind();
                }
            }

     }
```

ds = data.GetCorpCode(); is equal to this:

```
public DataSet GetCorpCode()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@RowId",sRowId)
        };

        if (this.InitDataLayerObject() == true)
        {
            ds = this.ExecuteQuery("dbo.sp_ESS_RFP_GetCorpCode", sqlParam);
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

It's a stored procedure, here is my stored procedure "dbo.sp_ESS_RFP_GetCorpCode"

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ESS_RFP_GetCorpCode] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @RowId varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @xml as xml

    select      
            @xml =convert(xml,CORPCODE)
        from Tbl_ESS_Request_For_Payment_Save
            where ROWID=@RowId

        select 
            tbl.col.value('CorpCode[1]', 'varchar(100)') as CorpCode,
            tbl.col.value('Amount[1]', 'varchar(100)')as Amount     
        from @xml.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1') tbl(col)

END
```

What I want is to have a javascript equivalent to private void fillCorpCode to populate it on my gridview, BTW, You might ask why I need a javascript if i already have a code in c#, It's because of some process in my program and it is difficult to explain. So please help me on this one, thank you in advance!

Comment: There are a number of javascript frameworks/plugins that will create a data-grid view with minimal configuration, if that's what you are looking for.  Search for 'datatable javascript' or 'grid view javascript' and you'll find a number of them.

Comment: You need to make a getJSON call in your javascript function. get the DS serialzed to JSON object and construct a HTML table to display like Gridview. When you say grid view it has its assoxiated benefits like event handlers, properties etc.. which will not be avbl if you do in js

Comment: @Saravanan Can you answer my question in a code? I have no idea on getJSON.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
   function getJSONData(selVal, callbackName) {
            selVal = encodeURI(selVal);
            var formdata = {  };// any data you want to pass as input
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "aspx",
                data: formdata,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    callbackName(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Error in processing data !!' + thrownError);
                },
                async: false
            });
        }

  function createTable() {
            mytable = $('<table Class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
            // alert(rowData);
            var rowobj = JSON.parse(rowData);
            // To populate header
            var firstrow;
            var firstrow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
            $('<td></td>').text('Entity Name').appendTo(firstrow);
            $('<td></td>').text('Attribute Name').appendTo(firstrow);
            $('<td></td>').text(' Value').appendTo(firstrow);

            // To populate rows
            $.each(rowobj, function (i, obj) {
      $('<td valign="middle"></td>').text(obj.ParentName).appendTo(row);
 $('<td valign="middle"></td>').text(obj.ParentName1).appendTo(row);
 $('<td valign="middle"></td>').text(obj.ParentName2).appendTo(row);});
}
//C# method
   [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
        public static string Mymethod(string entityName, string entityType, string filterValues)
        {
            List<MasterFields> fields = null;
            ServiceWrapper<ILOSService>.Perform(svcClient =>
            {
                fields =  getfields();
            });


            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string output = jss.Serialize(fields);
            return output;
        }
```